# Merging 1D and 2D lists in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to set up data to convert to a numpy array.  I have three lists.  Two are one dimensional, and one is two dimensional.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [ [7,8],[9,10],[11,12] ]
```

I want to end up with this:

```
[ [1,4,7,8],[2,5,9,10],[3,6,11,12] ]
```

I've tried using `zip()`, but it doesn't delve into the 2D array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind if the use of NumPy in the conversion itself, the following should work.

```
from numpy import array

a = array([1, 2, 3])
b = array([4, 5, 6])
c = array([[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])

result = array(list(zip(a, b, c[:, 0], c[:, 1])))
```

Note that `c[:, n]` will only work with NumPy arrays, not standard Python lists.

Comment: This works fine for the simple case, but doesn't scale or adapt well to changes.  If array c contains a large number of columns, it means having to address each one individually: `c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c[:, 3], ...`

Answer (score 4):

With `python3` it's as simple as

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [ [7,8],[9,10],[11,12] ]
[[x, y, *z] for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)]
[[1, 4, 7, 8], [2, 5, 9, 10], [3, 6, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: my bad, I did not realize my python interpreter is actually 3.5

Comment: Older versions of Python 3 will choke on the `*z`.  3.0 through 3.4 raise `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`.

Answer (score 3):

A `numpy` solution (as per your tag) would be

```
In [398]: np.vstack([a,b,np.array(c).T]).T
Out[398]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 2,  5,  9, 10],
       [ 3,  6, 11, 12]])
```

this makes `c` into a 2x3 array:

```
In [399]: np.array(c).T
Out[399]: 
array([[ 7,  9, 11],
       [ 8, 10, 12]])
```

which can then be stacked (concatenated) vertically with `a` and `b` which also have 3 elements.

`zip(*c)` is a list form of transpose

```
In [412]: list(zip(a,b,c)) 
Out[412]: [(1, 4, [7, 8]), (2, 5, [9, 10]), (3, 6, [11, 12])]

In [418]: list(zip(a,b,*zip(*c)))
Out[418]: [(1, 4, 7, 8), (2, 5, 9, 10), (3, 6, 11, 12)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to operate with standard Python lists you can use `zip` and then process each row afterwards:

```
from itertools import chain

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [[7,8], [9,10], [11,12]]

[list(chain.from_iterable(y if isinstance(y, list) else [y] for y in x)) for x in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `zip` yields tuples, not lists, so you'd have to convert its output into lists:

```
def lzip(*args):
    'Transforms the tuples yielded by zip into equivalent lists.'
    for tup in zip(*args):
        yield list(tup)
    return

# Later...
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [
  [7, 8],
  [9, 10],
  [11, 12],
  ]
lzip(a, b)
# A generator that yields: [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]
```

Second, `zip` won't return what you want no matter what, because the operation you're trying to perform on the sub-lists of `c` is *concatenation*, not zipping.

First, `lzip` the 1-d lists as in the example above, then concatenate each sublist that results with the matching sublist in `c`.

Below, I've used a list comprehension to build the combined list assign it to a variable, with two new local variables to make the `zip` operation more clear:

```
heads = lzip(a, b)
tails = c
zipped = [head + tail for head, tail in zip(heads, tails)]
# [[1, 4, 7, 8], [2, 5, 9, 10], [3, 6, 11, 12]]
```

The `zip` yields 2-tuples containing the *n*⁠th head and *n*⁠th tail:

```
# First iteration:
([1, 4], [7, 8])
# Next iteration:
([2, 5], [9, 10])
# Last iteration:
([3, 6], [11, 12])
```

These tuples are unpacked into two variables by the (invisible) assignment `head, tail = ...` inside the list comprehension.  The tuples themselves are then thrown away.

Concatenating ("adding") lists with `head + tail` combines two lists into one.  In this case, pairs of 2-element lists become individual 4-element lists.

Finally the `[` and `]` of the list comprehension collect the 4-element lists into a single list... of 4-element lists.